# Редирект на https и www в htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Сейчас в .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^сайт\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.сайт.ru/$1 [R=301]
```

То есть настроен редирект на "www". Попросил поддержку хостинга помочь с редиректом, они прислали:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как объединить все эти правила так, чтобы в любом случае, как бы ни набрал пользователь, он перенаправлялся на `https://www`? Я пробовал так:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^сайт\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.сайт.ru/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^.*$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Но ошибка в браузере "слишком много перенаправлений". Пытался смотреть в похожих темах, но что-то не соображу все равно никак.

UPDATE:

Получилось сделать рабочий вариант:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^сайт\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.сайт.ru/$1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Но теперь, если ввести `http://сайт.ru` в логе браузера видно, что идет 2 редиректа: `http://сайт.ru -> https://сайт.ru`, а потом `https://сайт.ru -> https://www.сайт.ru`

Наверное, так не должно быть...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Никто так и не ответил. Не знаю, удалять или нет тему.

В итоге правильно настроить переадресацию на `https://www` удалось так:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^сайт\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.сайт.ru/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

Позже обратил внимание, что разные сайты действуют по разному в плане редиректа, если набрать не так, как им нужно. Сейчас взял запрос "пластиковые окна" в яндексе: 1-й сайт в топе делает два 301-х редиректа: сначала обработка "www", потом добавляется https. А второй сайт в топе делает все одним редиректом (как в моем примере - выполняется только один редирект в любом случае). По идее, странно, зачем 2 раза перенаправлять, но видимо это не ошибка, так как у гугла тоже 2 редиректа, если набрать "http://google.ru":

[image: Редиректы google'a]

Comment: Ваш самоответ может быть полезен другим участникам с похожей проблемой. Просто отметьте Ваш ответ как решение. Не расстраивайтесь, что Вам никто не помог, возможно не было времени или не заметили Ваш вопрос.

Comment: Понял, спасибо =)

Comment: спасибо за решение=) весь инет перерыл и получал двойной редирект, ваше помогло сделать все правильно

Comment: Автору спасибо! Долго искал выход из описанной ситуации. Нашел здесь)